# Why does Chrome not follow each of resources' priority order when downloading them?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Suppost I have this index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="prefetch" as="image" href="./assets/footer.jpg" />
    <script
      async
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./utils.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

According to this [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc/edit#)
async script has **Low** priority, and css has **Highest** priority, so why does the jquery-3.3.1.js was downloaded before style.css downloaded when I Ctrl+F5 to refresh the whole page? (And you can see footer.jpg was at the end due to **Lowest** priority because of **prefetch**, but why async script not works in the same way?)

[click me to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP71P.png)

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong?  My Chrome version: 107.0.5304.107

To me, the reasonable order should be:

- localhost (Highest)
- style.css (Highest)
- utils.js (High)
- jquery-3.3.1.js (Low)
- footer.jpg (Lowest)

Comment: In your screenshot, the order seems correct. utils.js is low because you are loading it in the body. Can you try the same again with bandwith throttled?

Comment: @DanielW. Thanks for reply. I throttled it to Slow 3G but the result remains same. :(   Does brandwidth throtteld affect the priorities applied to the resources? I think that brandwidth throttled only affect the time spent on downloading, not the priority . If I'm wrong then please telling me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bandwidth doesn't affect the priority but it's clearer to see the priority in action. You don't see it clearly with high bandwidth. Priority, especially async, is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dimava and @Daniel W., Thank you very much for your kind answers , I think I have found the answer :)

According to the [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc/edit#) here:

> Chromium loads resources in 2 phases. “Tight mode” is the initial phase and constrains loading lower-priority resources until the body is attached to the document (essentially, after all blocking scripts in the head have been executed). In tight mode, low priority resources are only loaded if there are less than 2 in-flight requests at the time that they are discovered.

Because when html parser see the async script for jquery, there's no in-flight requests, so it was started downloading at once even if it has low priority, thus started downloading **before** style.css was.

Consider another situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="prefetch" as="image" href="assets/footer.jpg" />
   <script src="utils.js"></script>
   <script src="another.js"></script>
   <script
    async
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
   ></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the result is here, we can see that when html parser see the async script for jquery, there're two in-flight requests (for utils.js and another.js), so it is downloaded at the time body is attached to the document , thus started downloading **after** style.css was.
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Priority is not the order to be downloaded

Priority is the order to *start* downloading if there's many resources

Chrome generally uses 5 download threads, so if there's less then 6 resources they start downloading at once, and generally finish downloading depending on their size

---

That may be different only on very slow (<10kb/s) networks, try reducing web speed in devtools to check what happens

Comment: In the screenshot provided, they don't start all at once. The sum of assets is not known when the source is read from top to bottom and the first downloads are initiated. Your answer doesn't seem to be correct and doesn't provide much details into what exactly is happening with reference to official resources